# Categorical data in SEM using AMOS. How to code and interpret results?

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling

I'm using AMOS for carrying out a SEM in which I have a categorical variable measuring a latent construct. Do I have to code different variables with 0-1 (dummy) in order to find which one affects the latent construct? Do I need to correlate them? 
Or do I need to have only one predictor variable composed of different categories? In this last case, how can I interpret which one affects the latent construct?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. A multilnomial variable can't represent a continuous latent variable in this way.

Comment: Can you describe the nature of the data more thoroughly? Outright, my inclination is to say no.